# Access Page Header from within a Class

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to access a Page Header (Me.Page.Header) from within a class?

I'm working in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, try `HttpContext.Current.Page.Header`.

**EDIT:**
This should do the trick:

```
Dim p As Page = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
'p.Header.Whatever
```

Comment: Sorry, Tried that.  Page is not a member of HttpContext

Comment: As I was waiting, I started fiddling with a concept.  I created a function that required two parameters... one being the path to css and the other being the header.  Calling my function from a page now looks like "HelperClass.AddStyleSheet("~/path/to/file.css", Me.Page.Header)"

Comment: That would work, but if you look at my Edited answer, it shows how to access the Page object directly so you don't need to pass in extra parameters.